# Jtable and mysql auto incremental

Tags: java, mysql, excel

Jtable and mysql auto incremental
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(int, int)" is null

Hai, im new to java and mysql. i want to make a database system where i can upload my data to jtable and then i can import it to mysql. but i just got a problem where Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value of "javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(int, int)" is null. can i know any tips for doing this kind of system. thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tips: Create a separate application model using one or more plain Java getter/setter classes.  When and only when you successfully attach to your database, read information from the database, and write information to the database do you even consider coding the GUI.